# Lost files while moving. Best strategy for recovery. (yes, I was unwary)

Tags: data-recovery, move

I had moved some files (each between 20 and 200 MiB in sum approx 1 GiB) from an internal HD (ext3) to an external HD (ext3). Usually I do a copy-compare-delete scheme for moving files, but this time I let my guard down.
Unfortunately I had used the filebrowser of the GUI instead of the shell. While copying the USB link got unstable and the transmission terminated. External disk was unmounted by fuse. However the progress bar was just reaching the end when that happened, so I hope that most of the data was written to the external HD.

After restoring the connection, the files at the origin were gone, i.e. deleted by the file browser. At the destination a bunch of the files (I'm not sure how many there were in the beginning) showed up, but with one exception have 0 size.

I want to come up with a strategy to salvage the data.

At the origin, there were only 2.5 GiB free space left. So if I try to search for the deleted content, at least there's only limited volume to search.

At the destination, there's plenty space, so I can assume, the files were written continguously.

My idea is to somehow dd all the free space from the origin to a safe place and try to dd data up to 1 GiB from the destination starting at the beginning of the empty files.

When having salvaged those fragments I think I can compare the fragments from origin and destination to make a conclusion on the data.

However, I neither know how to get the data from the free space of a partition, nor how to get the data from a file which is erroneously marked as 0 size.

Or is there a better way to get a grip on my data?

Comment: R-Studio Undelete

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Interesting thing. I wasn't aware of a commercial/semi-commercial solution for these types of problems.

Comment: One of the best proprietary ext2/ext3/ext4 recovery programs on the market.